# android app is closed after installing new version

Tags: android, react-native

I have an existing react native app that I added some features and want to update it grammatically. my problem is after installation my app is closed for no reason but app updates seccussfully. how can I prevent this

my build.gradle

```
ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
```

my react-native download section

```
downloadClick = async () => {
        const { Model } = this.props;
        try {
            await requestPermission(Permissions.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, trans('STORAGE_MESSAGE'));
            await requestPermission(Permissions.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, trans('REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES'));
            this.downloading(true);
            const filePath = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/com.rasapayam.apk`;
            RNFS.downloadFile({
                // fromUrl: Model.ApkLink.value,
                fromUrl: "https://srv-file7.gofile.io/download/2Oyk8V/rasa-60.apk",
                toFile: filePath,
                progress: (res) => {
                    this.setState({ progress: (res.bytesWritten / res.contentLength) });
                },
                progressDivider: 1,
            }).promise.then((result) => {
                this.downloading(false);
                if (result.statusCode === 200) {
                    MimeIntent.openURLWithMime(filePath, 'application/vnd.android.package-archive');
                }
            }).catch((err) => {
                this.downloading(false);
            });
        } catch (err) {
            ToastAndroid.show(trans('VERSION_ERROR'), ToastAndroid.SHORT);
            this.setState({ progress: 0 });
        }
    }
```

my android native module for installing downloaded apk

```
@ReactMethod
    public void openURLWithMime(String url, String mime, Promise promise) {
        if (url == null || url.isEmpty()) {
            promise.reject(new JSApplicationIllegalArgumentException("Invalid URL: " + url));
            return;
        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(_context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();
            Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(_context, "com.rasapayam", new File( url));
            Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            install.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
            install.setData(contentUri);
            if (currentActivity != null) {
                currentActivity.startActivity(install);
            } else {
                getReactApplicationContext().startActivity(install);
            }
            promise.resolve(true);
        }
    }
```

my manifest's provider on the application's tag

```
 <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.rasapayam"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

my provider xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path name="external_files" path="." />
    <root-path name="root" path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert here, but I am quite confident that it is natural behavior on android, when you install new app it needs to be closed, Google Play does the same the app closes when it updates. What you would most likely want to achieve is some kind of an OTA update. You can achieve that with Code Push AFAIK.

Comment: With target sdk 23 after installation it shows done and open but with these code after installation app closed without showing anything and unfortunatly the code that works with target sdk 23 dosent work on android 9 and 10

Answer (score 0):

That is a normal rule. Remember when you use Android Studio. When you run an app in your phone or emulator then further run it with an update the app interface closes then installs the new apk. that is a default process. When you install an app with same package name it replace the previous version. this need to stop the current process.

Comment: With target sdk 23 after installation it shows done and open but with these code after installation app closed without showing any thing